# Is it possible to combine external and internal filtering in ui-grid?

Tags: filter, angular-ui-grid

I am using 'useExternalFiltering' in angular ui-grid.
Is it possible to set 1 column to still filter internally (sort out based on the table data)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. You can set `useExternalFiltering: true` on the columns that need it and use the normal filtering on the other. (In fact, on the column I use external filtering with in my grids, it also works as a normal filter once the data have been retrieved, but I imagine this could be disabled.)

Comment: I need all of my columns to use external filtering, except 1 that should filter internally. I thought there will be an attribute to set on that single column only. Anyway, the external filtering should act on the server data, not the table. Meaning I need to disable the internal filtering on those columns

Comment: I edited my answer a bit. What I am wondering though is if you have tried it and did it not work to your satisfaction? I have a setup where I mix internal and external filtering and it works fine.